# Javascript basic mediaplayer

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

So some friends and I are working on a project to make a simple mediaplayer using the audio tag. Something isn't working. Not sure what though... Please help

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function defAudio() {
        var def = playRandom();
        var format = '.mp3';
        var title = '&quot;+def+format+&quot;';
        document.getElementById('media').src=&quot;+def+format+&quot;;
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=title+'has been selected';
    }
    function playRandom() {
        var mp3 = dBase();
        for (var i = 0; i < mp3.length; i++) {
            var selVal = mp3[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)];
            var gen = mp3[selVal];
            return gen;
        }
    }   
    function dBase() {
        var songs = array();
        songs[0] = 'A Prophecy';
        songs[1] = 'The Final Episode';
        songs[2] = 'When Everyday is the Weekend';
        return songs;
    }

    /*function select() {}*/
</script>
</head>
<body onload='defAudio()'>
<p id='iface'>
<audio controls>
    <source id='media' src='' type='audio/mpeg'>
    Unexpected Error!
</audio>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### EDIT

It is supposed to randomly pick a song from the three. All in the same directory so that's not an issue. If I directly input the song names it works.

Comment: `Something isn't working.`? Pretty vague problem description.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the paragraph with the id "test" when I posted on here so that shouldn't matter. Also we plan on using a database for the songs but temporarily I just made a function called dBase. I have one friend working on the database, another on graphics, and I'm doing this stuff.

Comment: Well @dfsq I didn't know what else to say because I don't know what's wrong

Comment: No errors? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well @dfsq it should onload run the function defAudio which then goes through the process of choosing the default audio which should randomly be generated but doesn't. the .scr=&quot; and all of that is correct. I think something is wrong with running the other functions and returning them. They need to be set up like that though because function will serve it's own purpose in the long run when there is A LOT more going on. Just trying to get the basics down first and make sure that it will work the way I'm trying to think of

Answer (score 0):

In that code you're calling the `defAudio()` function when the body loads, and that's probably before the `<audio>` tag isn't still loaded. That may be one problem.

I've also seen that in this code

`var title = '&quot;+def+format+&quot;';`

You've included everything into a string, as it's between quotes. So then all of it will be treated as a string with that exact text (no the variables' values) and that title will look like `&quot;+def+format+&quot;`

And you've messed up with this other code as well

`document.getElementById('media').src=&quot;+def+format+&quot;;`

and you've done the opposite thing. That two `&quot` should be between quotes, or they will be treated as variables and their `;` will stop the program line at that point.

(Sorry about my syntax, I'm not from an English-speaking country)

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed you weren't your english is pretty good. I'll get back to you tomorrow. All of this code is just coming out of me tonight so I'm trying to cram it down without thinking AND at 4 am night friend and thank you for your post